# jQuery doesn't work inside ASP.NET user control with updatepanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, webusercontrol

I have nested user controls on the page having the following hierarchy:

Master Page -> Content Page -> UpdatePanel -> User Control -> UpdatePanel -> Child User Control

I am trying to do a basic thing writing to the console when Child User Control is loaded\reloaded like this (this code snippet is sitting within Child User Control):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Child control loaded');
    });

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
        console.log('Child control re-loaded');
    });
</script>
```

but it doesn't work.

I am using pageLoad() function on the Content Page so having another one in the Child User Control is not an option. Also I don't want all my jQuery reside on Content Page and I want each User Control be responsible for maintaining required jQuery code that's why I am trying to figure out how to get it to work in my Child User Control. I've read a good number of posts here related to this issue but nothing works for me yet. Am I missing something?

Update 1

I pinpointed a problem to be with the Wizard control that I have on the Content Page, my user controls are inside Wizard steps and none of them firing jQuery events but once I move them out they work perfectly fine. I am still looking for a solution to work around this.

Comment: You have answered yourself: _I know that I can use pageLoad() function_.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I need to update the post. What I meant to say was that I am using pageLoad() function somewhere else and I can't use it again in the Child User Control because JavaScript engine will execute the last function only declared within the page with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before.  All you need is a global array that stores the functions so that from one function you can loop through and fire them.  That one function you call from the PRM.

**Top of your main script file**

```
var func = [];

function abc123 () { console.log( "abc123 () fired" ); }
func[ func.length ] = abc123;
```

**In your nested user control script file**

```
function def456 () { console.log( "def456 () fired" ); }
func[ func.length ] = def456;
```

**Bottom of your main script file**

```
function fireFunctions () { for (var i = 0; i < func.length; i++) func[i](); }
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest( fireFunctions );
```

[Here's a CodePen that shows how the functionality works](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yCDEt).  Obviously it can't use User Controls or UpdatePanels, but it might help to see how it works.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I like your solution but it doesn't work for me. All the functions on the Content Page work fine but not on User Controls. At some point I thought that having UpdateMode set to Conditional on UpdatePanels would cause this but that was not the case either. I am truly puzzled by this issue. What else I can do to troubleshoot it?

Comment: First, I would comment out the UpdatePanels and see if you can get the above to work inline with your User Controls.  As a side note, if you are using MasterPages, you can create a ContentPlaceHolder in your <head/> or at the bottom of the MasterPage (which is what I do) for scripts.  Then in your ContentPages you can use that ContentPlaceHolder to put their specific scripts that will only load when that page is loaded.